# SQL Date intersection

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to figure out if any dates in a table for a particular ID overlap. Here is an example of my table

```
ID   |  EffDate    | ExpDate
---------------------------------
1    |  2000-01-01 | 2010-12-31
2    |  2000-01-01 | 2050-12-31
1    |  2011-01-01 | 2011-12-31
1    |  2011-12-31 | 2050-12-31
```

In `TableA` I need to check to make sure that none of the ID's intersect with "themselves" so none of the 1's can intersect with any other one but doesn't matter if the eff and exp dates intersect with ID 2.

Not looking for a complete answer just a starting point.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need to prevent invalid rows from appearing in the table (due to inserts and/or updates), or just detect that such a situation has come into existence at a later point in time?

Comment: Is there a primary key? Which version of Sql Server is this?

Comment: I need to detect and report to the user that the situation has occurred.

Comment: Cannot be as it is duplicated. How do you uniquely identify a record?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This finds an overlap between two of your rows with `ID` equal to 1:

```
declare @TabA table (ID int,EffDate datetime2,ExpDate datetime2)
insert into @TabA(ID,EffDate,ExpDate) values
(1,'20000101','20101231'),
(2,'20000101','20501231'),
(1,'20110101','20111231'),
(1,'20111231','20501231')

select
    * --TODO -Pick columns
from
    @TabA t1
        inner join
    @TabA t2
        on
            t1.ID = t2.ID and
            t1.EffDate <= t2.ExpDate and --Play with these
            t1.ExpDate >= t2.EffDate and --For Inclusive/Exclusive
            t1.EffDate < t2.EffDate
```

Result:

```
ID          EffDate                ExpDate                ID          EffDate                ExpDate
----------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ----------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1           2011-01-01 00:00:00.00 2011-12-31 00:00:00.00 1           2011-12-31 00:00:00.00 2050-12-31 00:00:00.00
```

You can play with the comparison operators to make either or both of `EffDate` and `ExpDate` inclusive or exclusive boundary values.

Comment: This only get the overlaps where t1.EffDate < t2.EffDate.  It misses overlaps where  t1.EffDate > t2.EffDate

Comment: @Blam - I've got that in to prevent every overlap being reported twice - there's otherwise no distinguishing feature between rows from `t1` and `t2`...

Comment: If intersect is to not include contained the I think you need to add a condition t1.ExpDate >  t2.ExpDate

Answer (score 0):

I think there may be a pretty simple solution to this one:

```
    select  distinct ta2.*
    from    #TableA ta1 join #TableA ta2 on 
            (ta1.EffDate > ta2.EffDate and ta1.EffDate < ta2.ExpDate)
            or (ta1.ExpDate > ta2.EffDate and ta1.ExpDate < ta2.ExpDate)
```